# React Native: how to make a view sticky after it reaches top inside scrollview

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I want to make a view sticky when it reaches the top of the screen inside scrollview.
I want to achieve something like this:

as you scroll down, as long as the "go stick" view reaches the top of the screen, it remains sticky there.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, you are searching for the [stickyHeaderIndices](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#stickyheaderindices) property.

You pass it the array of indexes of the children you want to be sticky when they arrive at the top. There is only one sticky element at a time.

For example you have 20 children in your ScrollView and you want the 3rd to stick to the top you pass this array: `[2]`.

You use it like this:

```js
<ScrollView stickyHeaderIndices={[2]}>
    {data.map((item)=>(
        <Item key={item.id} title={item.title} category={item.category} />
    ))}
</ScrollView>
```

Here is an [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@misterorrange/sticky-header) in a snack (only works on mobile, not on web).

PS: For ScrollViews with a lot of children it is more performant to use a FlatList.